# QPropertyAnimation is not saving the last positon of the widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to use multiple QPropertyAnimation to move a widget up, then right.

**Here is the code :**

```
QPropertyAnimation* animationUp;
QPropertyAnimation* animationRight;

QSequentialAnimationGroup *group;

animationUp = new QPropertyAnimation(this->ui->pushButton_2, "geometry");
animationUp->setStartValue(QRect(this->ui->pushButton_2->pos().x(), this->ui->pushButton_2->pos().y(), buttonWidth, buttonHeight));
animationUp->setEndValue(QRect(this->ui->pushButton_2->pos().x(), this->ui->pushButton_2->pos().y() - 60, buttonWidth, buttonHeight));

animationRight = new QPropertyAnimation(this->ui->pushButton_2, "geometry");
animationRight->setStartValue(QRect(this->ui->pushButton_2->pos().x(), this->ui->pushButton_2->pos().y(), buttonWidth, buttonHeight));
animationRight->setEndValue(QRect(this->ui->pushButton_2->pos().x() + 60, this->ui->pushButton_2->pos().y(), buttonWidth, buttonHeight));

group = new QSequentialAnimationGroup;
group->addAnimation(animationUp);
group->addAnimation(animationRight);

group->start();
```

The probleme is simple, the widget will move up, then move right BUT from the starting position, not from the position after the up movement. I want it to move up then right from the last position, not from the starting position.

**EDIT :**

The answer from @eyllanesc is working fine for the question I asked but I should have been more precised in what I was planning to do. The Up and Right animation was just a test, my goal is to be able to move a button Up, Down, Left or Right with possibly multiple movements in the same direction. For example, here is what it could look like :

```
group->addAnimation(animationUp);
group->addAnimation(animationUp);
group->addAnimation(animationUp);
group->addAnimation(animationRight);
group->addAnimation(animationDown);
group->addAnimation(animationLeft);
group->addAnimation(animationLeft);

group->start();
```

In this case, the answer is not working anymore. I've tried 2 settings and got differents problems :

```
//Setting 1 : Only one of the Up animation is showed, the other is ignored

group->addAnimation(animationUp);
group->addAnimation(animationUp);
group->addAnimation(animationRight);


//Setting 2 : Up and Right working fine but the last Up starts from the starting position

group->addAnimation(animationUp);
group->addAnimation(animationRight);
group->addAnimation(animationUp);
```

Comment: You could be more explicit in the type of movement

Comment: The type of movement is not yet defined, the sequence will be chosen by the user. There is 4 movements possible, Up, Down, Left and Right, all of them is a translation of 60 unit. The user will be able to chose from all these movements to create the sequence of his choice.

Comment: update my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning the positions with respect to the initial position of the button, you must create a `QRect` variable and modify it with `translate()`

```
QPropertyAnimation* animationUp;
QPropertyAnimation* animationRight;

QSequentialAnimationGroup *group;

QRect r(ui->pushButton_2->pos(), QSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight));

animationUp = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->pushButton_2, "geometry");
animationUp->setStartValue(r);
r.translate(0, -60);
animationUp->setEndValue(r);

animationRight = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->pushButton_2, "geometry");
animationRight->setStartValue(r);
r.translate(60, 0);
animationRight->setEndValue(r);

group = new QSequentialAnimationGroup;
group->addAnimation(animationUp);
group->addAnimation(animationRight);

group->start();
```

Also if you are not going to change the size of the button you can use the position instead of the geometry.

```
ui->pushButton_2->resize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
QPropertyAnimation* animationUp;
QPropertyAnimation* animationRight;

QSequentialAnimationGroup *group;
QPoint p = ui->pushButton_2->pos();


animationUp = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->pushButton_2, "pos");
animationUp->setStartValue(p);
p += QPoint(0, -60);
animationUp->setEndValue(p);

animationRight = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->pushButton_2, "pos");
animationRight->setStartValue(p);
p += QPoint(60, 0);
animationRight->setEndValue(p);

group = new QSequentialAnimationGroup;
group->addAnimation(animationUp);
group->addAnimation(animationRight);

group->start();
```

**Update**: A simple way is to create an enumeration by placing the possible movements and create a new animation, the animations do not refer to the previous state.

```
enum Movements{ Up, Down,Right, Left};
const auto dir = QList<QPoint>()<< QPoint(0, -1) << QPoint(0, 1)<<QPoint(1, 0)<<QPoint(-1, 0);


ui->pushButton_2->resize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);

auto group = new QSequentialAnimationGroup;
QList<Movements> Sequence_of_movements;

Sequence_of_movements << Up << Up << Up << Right<<Down<<Left<<Left;

auto p = ui->pushButton_2->pos();
int step = 60;
for(auto i: Sequence_of_movements){
    auto animation = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->pushButton_2, "pos");
    animation->setStartValue(p);
    p += step*dir.at(i);
    animation->setEndValue(p);
    group->addAnimation(animation);
}

group->start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's working for the Up and Right animation but I've got more problems, I edited my question.